# Nginx rewrite rule for dynamic parameters in url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

i have following url

```
https://domainname.com/folder1/folder2/script.php?&param1=%placeholder1%&pararm2=%placeholder2%&param3=%placeholder3%&
```

and i would like to get with **nginx** rewriting rule  following url:

```
https://domainname.com/%placeholder1%/%placeholder2%/%placeholder3%
```

how should be the config of /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default?

ps: url should working also with % (with haproxy working well)

Thank you in advance for all help

Comment: i getting 400 error

Comment: yes dont working for me, i edit my question again